# Relatived positioned children with column-fill parent

Tags: css, layout, css-position, semantic-ui

I wanted to create a layout where when the divs reach the bottom they will continue from the top. See my (super fancy) image I drew:
[image]

I got it working by using `column-fill: auto`. And now I'd like to add a dimmer on each item when being clicked. I'm using React and Semantic UI React for my app so I'm trying to achieve this with their [Dimmer](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dimmer/) component.

My problem is that when I active the dimmer, it's not "dimmering" the whole item. I made a small CodeSandbox for my problem so we can debug this more easily. When you press the third item you can see that the part who is coming from the top is not dimmed. I assume it because the position of the dimmer is `relative`.

LINK: https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-react-yl0dj

I hope I described my issue well enough and that we can solve this together.

Cheers!

Comment: I'm doubtful you can do this with an overlay regardless of positioning.

Comment: @Paulie_D That's what I'm feeling as well. Been trying to achieve a similar effect with CSS Grid and Flexbox, but failed. Side note, your comments have helped me many times over at css-tricks (recognized your profile pic) :-)